# How to round to end of month from a date

Tags: apex

I am trying to round a date to end of the month.How can we achieve it?

Eg: I have a date like 13/03/2019 it is middle of the month.i want it to be rounded to 31/03/2019 i.e, end of month.

I tried as below

```
datefield.addmonths().toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
```

but it is showing endof the month of previous month.
like 28/2/2019.

Comment: missing number of months to add. public Date addMonths(Integer additionalMonths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not compile. You have to pass an integer value to `addmonths()` method. Try with this code and check. You can use `format()` method as well to get string like 2/28/2019

```
Date datefield = System.today();
System.debug(datefield); //DEBUG|2019-02-07 00:00:00
System.debug(datefield.addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1)); //DEBUG|2019-02-28 00:00:00

Date endOfMonth = datefield.addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
System.debug(endOfMonth.format()); //DEBUG|2/28/2019
```

More on [date methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm).